# why database.emptyRecycleBin() not removing the actual record from bin?

Tags: apex, soql, community, database

```
database.emptyRecycleBin([select id from test__c where IsDeleted = true ALL ROWS]);
```

when i run the above and try to query the bin record, still record exist. What is wrong ? Please guide me !

Comment: which means its cleared th re-cycle bin but it will get clean up after 24 hours ?

Comment: that is correct. it is not exactly 24 hours. it can be more than that but from my personal experience with Salesforce support they store data for 45 days after purge so you might get them till that time.